# Android Java - ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am getting the following errors:

```
09-13 06:27:02.268: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1961)
09-13 06:27:02.268: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
09-13 06:27:02.268: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1315)
09-13 06:27:02.268: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
```

And below is my code:

```
private class DownloadVerses extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            String resultString = "";
            try {
                boolean resultBoolean = Utils.downloadTurboVerseFile(params[0]);

                if(resultBoolean){
                    int progressPercentage = Integer.parseInt(params[2].substring(0,params[2].indexOf(".")));
                    resultString = "Downloading: "+params[1];

                }
                else{

                    resultString = "ERROR Downloading: "+params[1];
                    this.doInBackground(params);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
                String exceptionString = e.toString();
            }

            return resultString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result.contains("ERROR")){
                downloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f05036"));

            }
            else{
                downloading.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#79a1ad"));

            }

            downloading.setText(result);

            if(checkIfVersesDownloaded()){

                downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                downloading.setText("Verses Have Been Downloaded.");
                homeButton.setEnabled(true);
                homeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

I am executing the code like this:

```
while(i < verseTitles.size()){      
  new DownloadVerses().execute(verseMp3s.get(i), verseTitles.get(i),progressString);
  i++;                                    
}
```

I am thinking there is probably a simple solution that involves adding some code to my DownloadVerses private class?

Comment: How big is `verseTitles.size()`?

Comment: verseTitles is 139 but It could be as much as 250. But let's just say 139.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a large number of `AsyncTask`s in a loop like that. You can create slightly more than 128 before you will get the error that you see.

Your options are:

1. Do not create individual tasks for each verse. For example, have one task that handles all verses.
2. Supply your own custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` that has a larger queue for pending tasks, and use that with `executeOnExecutor()` on `AsyncTask`.
3. Do not use `AsyncTask` at all, but something other background threading solution.